# Artificial Intelligence using sql query/stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, join, artificial-intelligence, distinct

I'm making an application that should organize employees to jobs.

One employee can't be in two jobs simultaneously.
Every employee has one or more qualifications.
Every job has one or more qualifications required for the job.
* All of the jobs should be staffed.

These are the tables:
1. Employees table - every person has PID number.
2. Qualifications table - [Id, Name].
3. QualificationsOfEmployee - every person can have more than one qualification [PID, QualificationId].
4. Jobs [Id, Name, NumOfEmployee(how much people is needed for job)]
5. QualificationsRequireForJob table - [JobId, QualificationId]

Now, I would like to make a query/function to find a qualified employee/s (depend on Jobs.NumOfEmployee) for every job.
The trick is that there is probably more than one qualified employee for every job, but some of them are maybe needed to other jobs (cause they have many qualifications).

I don't think a simple sql join or a sub-query could do the work.
Are there any ideas?

Thanks a lot,
Elad

Answer (score 1):

Mysql may not be the best language for this type of algorithm, but it's possible I guess.

You can (not the only way) implement a [genetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm).
These type of Algorithms are used to try to find the best combination for a given problem and prevents bruteforce test with all possibilities. Coupled with a powerufll cost function, it allow you to find a great solution (**may not** be the best).
This cost function, in your case may be calculated with the number of affected employees, jobs without employees, and number of qualifications of an affected employe (set a employe with 45 qualifications may be not the best solution if the job requiers just one qualif and other employees have this qualification). A diffuculty can be to find the best cost function.

"genetic Algorithm assignment" on Google may give you some papers with different algorithms which can fit to your problem.

Find the best combination in a assignement problem can be CPU expensive, and long to be executed. Depends on your algorithm and your set of data.

Good luck with these if you're going that way !

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! You helped a lot.